# I have an html/css code with transition. Transition works fine in Chrome, but fails in IE 11. Can someone point out the problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, transition

This code works fine on chrome and shows transition. But on IE 11, transition fails. I have tried removing the calc function, but it still doesnt work on IE 11. Here is the code,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>
    <style>
    .notch{position: absolute;

        left: calc(95vw - 37.5px);
        top: calc(50% - 5px);
        width: 75px;
        height: 110px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 110px;
        transition: all 60s linear;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="notch">NOTCH</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey @Libra2019, you might want to expand the explanation and code sample a bit. For example you are missing start state where you want the transitioning to start from. :)

Comment: Perhaps the easiest would be to have for example a hover on the element to show what you would like to achieve `.notch:hover{/*add your state want transition to*/}`

Comment: @ toni_lehtimaki . Thanks for your quick response. The problem is, I have to do this transition without hover. Is it possible to achieve simple transition in IE 11 without hover?

Comment: its a timer notch that has to move from left to right across the screen in 60 sec. Hover cant be used here

Comment: I see, maybe you could use e.g. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) to construct a working example. By definition [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) works between two states, so it helps to see both of the states. Do you use javascript to start the transition? That would be good to see too. :)

Comment: Thanks again. No I'm not using javascript, transition happens without js in chrome. Notch moves smoothly on chrome with above mentioned code. Dont know how to achieve it in IE 11.

Comment: Ok, I can not see how the above code could work (I tested this on chrome to be sure too :) ). If you want to do something on page load without javascript, you need use CSS animations and keyframes. See example from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and kindness :)

Answer (score 0):

The transition CSS property support IE 10 +, when using it in IE browser, we need to add the vendor prefix `-ms-`, like this: `-ms-transition: all 5s linear;`

Besides, with refer to [transition document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and the [CSS transition  Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp), I have created a sample on my side, it seems that it will not change the element's location just using the CSS transition property. As a workaround, we could change the element's location using [the Transition on Hover](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_transition_hover.asp) or using [the CSS animation Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp).

Please refer to the [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nv2fjy14/):

```
<style>
    .notch {
        position: absolute;
        left: calc(95vw - 37.5px); 
        top: calc(50% - 5px); 
        width: 75px;
        height: 110px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 110px;
        transition: all 5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 5s linear;
        -webkit-transition: all 5s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 5s linear;
        -o-transition: all 5s linear;
        -webkit-animation: mymove 5s linear; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
        animation: mymove 5s linear;
    }

    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        from {
            left: 195vw;
        }

        to {
            left: 95vw;
        }
    }

    @keyframes mymove {
        from {
            left: 195vw;
        }

        to {
            left: 95vw;
        }
    }
</style>
```

The output as below:

[image]